# What is the difference between these two phrases?

Tags: grammar, translation, words

I was creating some simple phrases using the help of Google Translator but it translated a phrase that I wrote:

> 君の車はあまり新しくない

But converted this exact phrase to:

> あなたの車はあまり新しいものではありません。

Well at least for me as a beginner in japanese, it sounded over complicated plus I don't know some words such as もので and I already heard of ありません which is the negative form of あります which by the way I don't know what it means.

Comment: Something like a difference between "Hey, your banger's pretty worn-out" and "Your vehicle doesn't really look that modern, mister"? Maybe not to that extent, but this direction. And context is king anyway, you can't tell just by a single sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The former is more casual, much more casual I would say, you should only use with people you are very close without sounding offensive. The latter is polite, but the use of あなた is complicated, I think the most natural thing would be to use the name of the person + honorific to sound right. None of them are incorrect, but you have to be careful while using each of them.

もの = thing
It is not もので, the character で makes part of ではありません which is a polite form of じゃありません or じゃない.

Answer (score 0):

I find Google Translate comes up with more polite sentence constructs, which the latter one is. The one you came up with, the former sentence, has a more casual tone. Neither one is incorrect.